# Overlay DIV sliding from the right

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addclass, toggleclass, animate.css

So I am trying to create a overlay menu that shows after the user clicks on the menu icon. This part is ok. But, I wanted it to show up sliding from the right.

I tried *slide*, I tried (and actually I prefer) animate.css classes and I just can't make it happen. The nearest I got was some blinking; sometimes, depending on the animation, the div doesn't even show up.

Here's a fiddle and the code with the animate.css's slideInRight so you guys could see it not working. :P

https://jsfiddle.net/aojzopbg/

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('.MenuClick').click(function() { 
$('#Menu').show().addClass('slideInRight'); 
});
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle slides in from the right for me in Chrome (once I added some content to the menu div so you could see it slide in).  What is not working the way you want?

Comment: is this what you are asking for? https://jsfiddle.net/aojzopbg/1/

Comment: I just can't believe the problem was the fact that there was nothing inside the sliding div, @NOBrien. That's it. It worked.

Comment: Yes, @Stacklearner. That's what I was asking for... The problem was the fact that there was no content inside the div. Never thought about it. Lesson learned. Thanks! :)